# Does the iPhone support TRIM for flash memory?

Tags: iphone, memory, ssd

I'm asking if TRIM is enabled on iOS because, ever since I ran out of memory on my iPhone (have since cleared a few GB back), it seems to be slower than it was before. My suspicion being that, with most flash memory "sectors" now partially used, every write operation now takes longer…

Relying heavily on flash memory, I wonder if the iPhone implements [TRIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM) (or any "trim-like" feature) to maximize flash memory performance and specifically if that will let me troubleshoot a slow phone and/or know if I would want to jailbreak the device to enable TRIM or otherwise control storage more tightly than iOS is delivered.

Comment: I've removed the second part of your question because this can't really be answered here.

Comment: I still have no ideia if iOS implements (or will implement) TRIM support in the future, but at least for Android - although it took them a while - it's coming with the new [Android 4.3 TRIM support](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7185/android-43-update-brings-trim-to-all-nexus-devices). (I imagine iOS won't be far behind in doing so, if it doesn't already.)

Comment: I see two reasons to open this, but I don't know which question you really have: 1) Yes or no - is there trim on iOS in general 2) How do I diagnose a slow phone whether or not it has TRIM. Since we prefer questions that are practical and discourage yes/no ones, I'll edit this assuming you really want to know #2 - anyone is free to edit this again and we can review / close again should it get too broad or unfocused down the line.

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm just a generic curious who can do some research on the web, I'll make here some assumptions so we can be on the same grounds:

- [TRIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM) is an [SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) technology and, as such, can mean **too many**  different things.
- [iPhone](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+4S+Teardown/6610/1?singlePage) uses [MLC NAND memory](http://appleinsider.com/articles/11/12/14/inside_anobit_why_apple_is_investing_in_flash_ram_technology), which [is indeed a SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory).
- We, people, (such as [dhy8386](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=13563790&postcount=9) and *maybe* even [Mr](http://www.brianklug.org/about/). [Brian Klug](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7185/android-43-update-brings-trim-to-all-nexus-devices)) love to talk big about things we don't know deep enough. To know more, trust less.
- Apple mostly does not disclose anything technically meaningful about their technology. And it does use many proprietary technologies nobody else does.
- Even today, the iPhone will work way more flawlessly under deep stress (filled memory, many applications, etc) than **any** Android or Windows Phone. (yes, I've used them all and I currently own a S3)

If you follow every link above deep enough, you may realize it's just not that simple. Even Android's TRIM support probably isn't the same TRIM as a notebook uses on its SSD.

So, it **doesn't matter** if it supports TRIM or not. The whole point of going with an iPhone is *trusting Apple* and letting them do the hardcore tech work. And the whole point of *jailbreaking* is being able to do things Apple can't allow for any reason, such as unblocking carriers. Anything else on JB is doing it wrong (specially now we have android, [even for iPhone](http://lifehacker.com/5693309/how-to-install-android-on-an-iphone-in-six-easy-steps)) - and I'm saying that from [my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device/4180498#4180498) heavy experience using jailbreak from iPhone 3 to 4.

Now, to address your main and unannounced question, **best thing you can do** to test if your hardware is malfunctioning is to backup your iPhone and **reset to factory**. Then fill it up with music or pictures, since you suspect a full disk is causing the malfunctioning, and avoid installing  applications at all. You probably won't see any problem and, if you do, just send it to warranty. You can also send it to warranty directly, but you risk of it coming back and just losing few days there.

Comment: I don't understand why you make the assumption the device is a jailbreak device. The asker never indicated that, and I arrived at this question because I suspected my iPhone could have the very problem. My iPhone  has never been jailbroken ... not even once. As for the difference between SSD and RAM, I don't see how that's relevant. I/O plays a critical role in system performance. If the SSD is slowing down, then the user will see a noticeable impact on performance.

Comment: @Avian00 because, back then, iPhone didn't have **multitasking**. It would be very difficult to load the memory up without having jailbreak (to allow multitasking). As for performance, I'll edit the question to add few points and updates that happened since then.

Comment: @Cawas My question had nothing to do with available RAM or multitasking, but with the performance of the flash storage subsystem before/after it had been completely filled up.

You'd get decent performance in one case, it would get worse after filling it up and freeing it again.

In Android, Google brought TRIM support to the Nexus in the latest 4.3 (took them long enough! :) I wonder if/when Apple does the same in iOS.

Comment: @Cawas Why the heck do you mix it up with RAM??

Comment: Interestingly Android 4.3 was the first Android to support TRIM on certain devices. I doubt iOS supports TRIM.

Comment: @ptnik you're right... I overlooked TRIM. I knew  SSD has many different characteristics from any other kind of memory, but I didn't know getting so slow when full was one of them - so I assumed only thing that could be slowing down was system performance. I'll change my answer soon enough.

Comment: @ptnik there. I heavily edited the answer. Hope it helps this time, in case you're *still* with that issue!

Comment: `Unrelated` is a weird beginning for an answer...

Comment: @Cawas again, I thank you for your effort, but it still is unrelated to the problem at hand. Wear levelling is a different thing from the intended issue: the write performance when flash blocks are partially written, or written then erased (but still not considered blank).

I've since upgraded to a new iPhone, and have yet to fill its memory (nor have any wish to do so in order to see if the same thing happens). As for the old iPhone, I suspect it would be fine after the full factory reset/wipe. However, the issue remains, and I hope iOS does implement TRIM to prevent performance degradation.

Comment: Well, you guys asked for it, I went deeper down on research and this is as far as I'll go in this question - specially because now I see @ptnik doesn't even have a problem any more and won't bother to try harder as well. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a question that can be answered with yes or no as it depends on both which kind of iPhone (model) and version of iOS, you're interested in.

In general I can say that TRIM is not used, simply because TRIM is a specific command found in the SATA protocol. As no iPhone uses a SATA storage interface, they cannot ofcourse implement TRIM.

The disk on the iPhone is actually a NAND flash directly soldered to the PCB in the phone. This means that there's no SATA-connector or PCIe connector or similar. However the actual electrical and logical protocols used for transferring data differs depending on model and iOS versions.

NAND flash chips work differently than an old fashioned hard drive. In order for the kernel and application software on an iPhone to treat them as a linear space of "blocks" or "bytes" something needs to happen.

On iOS 1 and 2 this was done through a flash translation layer called VFL. On iOS 3 and 4.0 Apple switched to using YaFTL and VSFL. On iOS 4.1 and later, they changed again to PPNFTL for those phones that had physical hardware with PPN (Perfect Page New NAND flash). Only on the PPN hardware is there are an actual controller inside the NAND flash. However most of the flash translation work actually still takes place in software.

In addition to handling the conversion between actual "flash realities" and the "linear space of blocks" logical view, the FTL is also responsible for doing wear-levelling. The functionality you know as TRIM is actually deeply rooted in the wear-levelling system.

The short answer is that the use of a "TRIM-like" functionality is very much dependent on your actual iPhone hardware model, the iOS version used and on whether or not Apple has actually decided to use the functionality. It is however clear that Apple designed the NAND layouts and flash translation layers to actually support a TRIM-like functionality, and they did this many years ago. So it would make sense that it is also being used. However it is not documented publicly whether or not Apple actually uses this TRIM-like functionality in practice.

You can read more about the layouts and flash translations layers in iOS/iPhone here:

http://esec-lab.sogeti.com/posts/2012/06/28/low-level-ios-forensics.html